# Install Ubuntu 17.04 alongside Windows 10 on a Lenovo Yoga 300 SD card

Tags: boot, dual-boot, lenovo, sd-card

I've successfully tried Ubuntu 17.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 300 using a live USB memory.
I've then installed ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on the removable SD card.
After rebooting and selecting "ubuntu", I see a grub prompt and I don't know how to proceed.
Unfortunately, I'm not skilled on linux: can you give me some instructions to boot ubuntu from a Lenovo Yoga 300 SD card?
Many thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Please show how exactly your grub prompt looks like. You can add a screenshot.

Comment: Hello Ajeet, the prompt is:<br/>GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta3-4ubuntu2<br/> Minimal BASH-like line editing. For the first word, TAB lists possible command competion. Anywere else TAB lists possible device or file completion<br/><br/> grub> </br>